# Polyglot frontend in microservices

Tags: frontend, microservices, ssi, esi

I'm new to microservices. In my project we're trying to break a monolith application into smaller microservices. 
It is fairly easy to implement backend systems with polyglot technology. Is the same achievable for frontend?
BFF (backend for frontend) seems to be a popular pattern to implement frontend in microservices. However, doesn't it result in frontend monoliths? Maybe my understanding of BFF is partial/incorrect.
There are few options such as SSI (server side includes) & ESI (Edge side includes) that could help in achieving polyglot in frontend.
But wasn't portlet technology trying to achieve something similar in early 2000's?
ESI is in trial stage at thoughtworks technology radar ([link](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/edge-side-includes-for-page-composition)). 
Do you think this is the right direction. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Polyglot frontend = Composite UI. https://www.google.co.uk/#q=composite+ui+microservices

Answer (score 0):

I would like to clarify few point in this context.

1. Microservices does not mandate Polyglot technology, it just gives you the flexibility.
2. Frond end design should follow your application needs and if your functional & non-functional requirements have a strong business case for using Polyglot technology for front-end you can. But microservices does not enforce anything.
3. Decision to choose ESI, BFF, SSI, Portlet etc. should be made purely based on your application and features fitment in to particular pattern.